# Is there a viable and satisfactory alternative word for the verb "feature"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, alternatives

Is there a viable and practical alternative word for the verb "feature"?

> [Feature](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/feature)
>
> [intransitive, transitive]
>
> **1** to include or show something as a special or important part of something, or to be included as an important part
>
> **2** Show a play, film, etc.

When I used this word in several conferences over the last few months, according to the audience's reaction and comments, I noticed that they did not understand what specifically I meant.

I flatly rejected the verb **show**, because it does not carry the above meaning.

& This is the context:

> "Striated muscle tissue is a muscle tissue that **features** repeating functional units called sarcomeres, in contrast with smooth muscle tissue which does not."

Source: ["Muscle Physiology - Introduction to Muscle". muscle.ucsd.edu. Retrieved 2015-11-24.](http://muscle.ucsd.edu/musintro/jump.shtml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative to **exhibits**, which is good, is the simpler **has|have**.

You can see that many scientific papers are content to use that simpler verb, if you do this google search: `"have sarcomeres" site:*.gov`

Comment: I like this answer. My googling found a lot of plagiarism with the word **feature** being used in the same replicated sentence. Some speakers / writers don't like using simple words like "show" and "have". The verbs **demonstrates** and **charaterises** could also be used.

Comment: (In spite of the fact that this answer is perhaps self-explanatory) This is the most attractive answer, I mean "what a terrific idea!"

Answer (score 3):

Isn't striated muscle tissue a **fault** and not a **feature**?

Sometimes computer engineers try to pass off a **bug** by saying it is a **feature** but the use here isn't appropriate. If you cannot feel able to use:

> Striated muscle tissue is a muscle tissue that **shows** repeating
>   functional units called sarcomeres, in contrast with smooth muscle
>   tissue which does not.

then I suggest [**exhibits**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/exhibit) from the Oxford dictionary with its example use

> 2.1 Show as a sign or symptom. ‘patients with alcoholic liver disease exhibit many biochemical abnormalities’

So your statement would be (removing the duplicated phrase):

> Striated muscle tissue **exhibits** repeating
>   functional units called sarcomeres, in contrast with smooth muscle
>   tissue which does not.